# How to map $eip in gdb to output of objdump -d?

Tags: gdb, objdump

I have an incomplete stacktrace which stops at a known library (linux i686 architecture). In order to ascertain the function last called, I am trying to map $eip as output by gdb, to an address within a file generated by "objdump -d library.so".
I thought I might be able to use the From address output from "info shared" within gdb, along with the $eip to calculate an offset, which I could then translate to an offset from the disassembly text section of the objdump -d output?
Not sure if this approach is sensible, but trying it in a simple test harness app with a shared library does not give me an address within the right function.
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought I might be able to use the From address output from "info shared" within gdb, along with the $eip to calculate an offset, which I could then translate to an offset from the disassembly text section of the objdump -d output?

Yes, that is exactly what you need to do.

The `From` address in GDB display tells you where `.text` section of the shared library was located.

The `readelf -S foo.so | grep '\.text'` will tell you offset of `.text` in the `foo.so` itself. Subtract one from the other, and you get the *relocation* for that shared library (it will be page-aligned).

Now take the `$eip` from GDB, subtract relocation, and you'll get an address that will match output of `nm` and `objdump` for `foo.so`.

*However*, GDB will have already completed all of the above steps internally. If it wasn't able to deduce which function `$eip` ended up in, you shouldn't expect that performing these steps manually will produce any better result.